# How does a pdf of the difference of two random variables relate to the pdf of each random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, random

Let $T_1$ and $T_2$ be non-negative continuous random variables (rv) denoted in the form $T_i = \mu_i + \sigma_i X_i$ for $i=1,2$ where 
\begin{eqnarray*}
T_{1} &=&\mu _{1}+\sigma _{1}X_{1} \\
T_{2} &=&\mu _{2}+\sigma _{2}X_{2}
\end{eqnarray*}

Suppose that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are ***iid*** with $f_{X_i} (x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ for $x\geq 0$ or zero otherwise.

Now define $Z=T_2 - T_1$ such that $Z=\mu_z + \sigma_z Y$; where $Y$ is a standardized rv with pdf $f_{Z}(z)$.

**Question:**

Express $f_Y(y)$ in terms of $f_{X_1}(x) \text{ and/or } f_{X_2}(x)$.

**Trial**

Following steps suggested by ***sds***; I arrived at the following.

I expressed the pdf of $T_{i}$ in terms of the pdf of $X_i$ starting from the CDF of these variables as follows.

\begin{equation*}
F_{T_{i}}\left( x\right) =F_{X_{i}}\left( \frac{x-\mu _{i}}{\sigma _{i}}
\right)  \mbox{ and } 
F_{-T_{i}}\left( x\right) = 1-F_{X_{i}}\left( \frac{-x-\mu _{i}}{\sigma
_{i}}\right) 
\end{equation*} 
hence 
\begin{equation*}
f_{T_{i}}\left( x\right) =\frac{1}{\sigma _{i}}f_{X_{i}}\left( \frac{x-\mu
_{i}}{\sigma _{i}}\right) \text{ and }f_{-T_{i}}\left( x\right) =\frac{1}{%
\sigma _{i}}f_{X_{i}}\left( \frac{-x-\mu _{i}}{\sigma _{i}}\right) 
\end{equation*}

Defining $-T_1 = Z-T_2 $ and using the convolution of pdfs, we have:
\begin{align*}
f_{Z}\left( z\right)  &=\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }f_{T_{2}}\left( x\right)
f_{-T_{1}}\left( z-x\right) dx \\
&=\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }\frac{1}{\sigma _{2}}f_{X_{2}}\left( \frac{x-\mu
_{2}}{\sigma _{2}}\right) \frac{1}{\sigma _{1}}f_{X_{1}}\left( z-\left( 
\frac{-x-\mu _{2}}{\sigma _{2}}\right) \right) dx \\
&=\left( \sigma _{1}\sigma _{2}\right) ^{-1}\int_{-\infty }^{\infty
}f_{X_{2}}\left( \frac{x-\mu _{2}}{\sigma _{2}}\right) f_{X_{1}}\left( z+%
\frac{x+\mu _{2}}{\sigma _{2}}\right) dx
\end{align*}

The integral is nonzero for $ \left( x>-\sigma _{2} z-\mu _{2}\right) \text{ and }\left( x>\mu _{2} \right) $ which is:

\begin{equation*}
\max \left( -\sigma _{2}z-\mu _{2},\mu _{2}\right) =\left\{ 
\begin{array}{l}
-\sigma _{2}z-\mu _{2}\text{ if }z\leq \frac{-2\mu _{2}}{\sigma _{2}} \\ 
\mu _{2}\text{ otherwise}%
\end{array}%
\right. 
\end{equation*}

First, I attempted deriving $f_{Z}\left( x\right) $ for $z\leq \frac{-2\mu _{2}%
}{\sigma _{2}}$ as:

\begin{equation*}
f_{Z}\left( z\right) =\left( \sigma _{1}\sigma _{2}\right)
^{-1}\int_{-\sigma _{2}z-\mu _{2}}^{\infty }f_{X_{2}}\left( \frac{x-\mu _{2}%
}{\sigma _{2}}\right) f_{X_{1}}\left( z+\frac{x+\mu _{2}}{\sigma _{2}}%
\right) dx
\end{equation*}

However, I am not sure about the limits of integration and if everything is correct, after all. I will appreciate any help on this!

Comment: @Henry I have now edited the sentence

Answer (score 1):

You need to take 3 steps:

1. Express the pdf of $T_1=\mu_1+\sigma_1 X_1$ in terms of $f_{X_1}$.
2. Express the pdf of $-T_2=-\mu_2-\sigma_2 X_2$ in terms of $f_{X_2}$.
3. Use the fact that the pdf of a sum of independent RVs is the convolution of the pdfs of the summands.